# Check on input field value in "where" clause

Tags: php

I want to make a check in the where clause like:

```
<input type="text" class="idcopy" name="idnumber">

"SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.TID = B.TID WHERE FIR_NO = inputfildvalue";
```

Is that possible to make a check like that in PHP? There is a permanent value in the field and I want to make a check on that value to filter the particular rows which will be only related to that value. Help would be nice.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here - could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, you can make database queries in PHP? What are you asking?

Comment: I just want to filter rows for which i need a where clause. like only those rows will be shown for which `FIR_NO = the value in the input`

Comment: acutally i am using a `class="idcopy"` to copy a value for example say 63 in the input field. i want that value in the where clause.

Comment: Unless you send data to the server and then make the query after, you will need some javascript to do that